# Hiding Nested Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react app I have I'm passing props for a view and two dropdowns. One dropdown is to let the user select an existing post to redirect to, the other is to choose a list from a 3rd party data source.
All of these are under three nested statements.

I don't want both of these dropdowns showing all the time, so I am trying to implement a simple dropdown function to hide the dropdown menu and the refresh list button:

```
{!this.props.view &&

    <div onClick={this.toggleHidden} className="dropdown-wrapper">
 {!this.state.isHidden && 
    <select
      className="dropdown">
      <option value="none">
        Redirect to an existing Post...
        </option>
      {this.props.sites
        .filter(site => site.site !== undefined)
        .map(site => (
          <option value={site.site.name} key={site.id}>
            {site.site.name}
          </option>
        ))}
    </select>
  }

    {emailProvider &&
      <select className="dropdown"
      >
      <option key={0}  value='none'>None</option>
      {
        emailProvider.length && emailProvider.length > 0 && emailProvider.map((eachData, key) => {
          return (
            <option key={key+1} value={eachData.id}>{eachData.name}</option>
            )
          })
        }
      </select>
     }

  <button style={{paddingTop: 14}}onClick = {this.handleClick}>Refresh List</button>
  </div>
  }
```

The hide function works for the first dropdown, but if I move the closing brace that is under the first`</select>` to after the `</button>`, the `{emailProvider &&` code can't find the closing brace which is under the second `select` option. It returns an error `}' expected` as if the closing bracket is not there.

How do I encapsulate the two dropdowns and stop this error from occurring?

Comment: The thing is return does not work like break statement. If you need somewhat like that functionality then you have yo use that.

Answer (score 0):

expression must have at least one parent element

```
{!this.props.view &&
    <div onClick={this.toggleHidden} className="dropdown-wrapper">
        {
            !this.state.isHidden ?
                <> {/*needs to be inside parent component*/}
                    <select
                        className="dropdown">
                        <option value="none">
                            Redirect to an existing Post...
                        </option>
                        {this.props.sites
                            .filter(site => site.site !== undefined)
                            .map(site => (
                                <option value={site.site.name} key={site.id}>
                                    {site.site.name}
                                </option>
                            ))}
                    </select>
                    <> {/*needs to be inside parent component*/}
                        {emailProvider &&
                            <select className="dropdown">
                                <option key={0} value='none'>None</option>
                                {
                                    emailProvider.length && emailProvider.length > 0 && emailProvider.map((eachData, key) => {
                                        return (
                                            <option key={key + 1} value={eachData.id}>{eachData.name}</option>
                                        )
                                    })
                                }
                            </select>
                        }
                    </>
                    <button style={{ paddingTop: 14 }} onClick={this.handleClick}>Refresh List</button>
                </>
                :
                null
        }
    </div>
```

}